# use of 'respectively', the correspondence

Tags: word-usage, grammar

It is a scientific paper. I have described two phenomena before, and now between

> These two phenomena are illustrated in Fig. 2a and 2b.

and

> Phenomenon A and B are illustrated in Fig. 2a and 2b, respectively

which is right?

Comment: You could say: "These two phenomena are illustrated in Fig. 2a and 2b respectively."

Comment: The word ***respectively*** is "valid" in your second example, but it's not really necessary. And even if you *do* include it, you don't want the comma. It doesn't really make sense to include ***respectively*** in the first example, since the sentence itself doesn't explicitly mention A and B. You can't expect the reader to go back to earlier text to see which sequence they were originally specified in - even if it's "obvious" that A came before B, that doesn't justify failing to include references to them in such constructions involving ***respectively***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think not including "respectively" in the second example might change the meaning. It makes clear that phenomenon A is illustrated in Figure 2a and phenomenon B is illustrated in Figure 2b, while without "respectively" all the reader knows is that those two figures illustrate the two phenomena, without indicating which figure is related to which phenomenon. I'd read the version without "respectively" as "both figures illustrate both phenomena equally".

Comment: @Maciej Stachowski: I understand what you're getting at (without ***respectively***, the first version is "agnostic" as to whether either or both phenomena are illustrated by either or both figures). But I just don't think it's idiomatic to use ***respectively*** unless the referents have just been identified (in the relevant sequence) *within the current utterance*. Of course, in this context an "utterance" might feasibly extend over two or more sentences, since they're really just an orthographic convention, but to a first approximation I'm thinking *within the current **sentence***.